# Break loop efficiently when figure exited Matlab

Tags: matlab, exit, figure

I've always had the same problem, and I'd really like to know if there's a solution to it. If I do something like:

```
figure
axis([-2 2 -2 2])
a=1;
h=rectangle('Position',[1,0,0.1,0.1]);
t=0;
while a==1
if ishandle(h)
t=t+0.1;
pause(0.001)
x=0.2*cos(t);
y=0.2*sin(t);
set(h, 'Position', [x, y,0.1,0.1])
else
break
end
end
```

I always get some sort of error when the figure is exited with the x button:

```
Error using handle.handle/set
Invalid or deleted object.
```

This isn't surprising, because if I exit while its reading the loop, it still has to go through it before it realizes that it should be breaking. One way to solve the errors is to add an "if ishandle(h)" everywhere I use something used outside of the loop. However, not only is this going to spam my code with if/end's at almost every line, it is also extremely slow to exit the code. This is the bigger issue, I don't mind the error that much, or spamming my code, but every time I exit I need to wait an extra 5 seconds where Matlab freezes for some reason.

Is that normal? Is there a more efficient way to close a figure? I'm thinking there has to be a listener for when the x button is clicked on a figure, that would just stop everything...

This is very frustrating and driving me mad, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: I use try set(h, ..) catch break end for that, it works fine but it might be considered ugly. What also helps is putting just the set statement after the ishandle() and the rest before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error systematically because your timing is wrong. You check for the existence of the handle, then you introduce your 1ms delay (`pause(0.001)`), and finally you update the object. All this short code in the loop execute rather rapidly and the actual "closing" of the window has 99.99% chance of happening during your delay.

If you simply re-order your code (place the check for handle **after** the delay (and preferably just before updating the object), the code will run fine and you will only get an error the odd 0.01% of the time when the actual "closing" will take place between the check and the object update.

```
while a==1
      t=t+0.1;
      pause(0.001)
      x=0.2*cos(t);
      y=0.2*sin(t);
   if ishandle(h)
      set(h, 'Position', [x, y,0.1,0.1])
   else
      break
   end
end
```

Note that your variable `a` is always `1` so the only reason to exit the loop is the deletion of the object `h`. So you could simplify your loop like:

```
while ishandle(h)
      set(h, 'Position', [x, y,0.1,0.1])
      t=t+0.1;
      x=0.2*cos(t);
      y=0.2*sin(t);
      pause(0.001)
end
```

Just make sure your delay is not between the check for the handle and the update of the object.

---

That should take care of the case in your example. If your actual code is much larger, consider using the `CloseRequestFcn` in the [`figure properties`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html). This is the listener you were asking about.

This method may be considered 'cleaner' than the trick above, but it will involve passing argument between the base workspace and the figure callback, which is not that clean if you ask me. It is best to keep this method for cases where you code belong to the gui and is not executed from a script in the base workspace.

Although I do not recommend it for such a simple case, one example would be:

```
hfig = figure('CloseRequestFcn', 'evalin(''base'', ''figExist=0'' )' ) ;
figExist = 1 ;
axis([-2 2 -2 2])
a=1;
h=rectangle('Position',[1,0,0.1,0.1]);
t=0;
while figExist
      set(h, 'Position', [x, y,0.1,0.1])
      t=t+0.1;
      x=0.2*cos(t);
      y=0.2*sin(t);
      pause(0.001)
end
delete(hfig) %// now we have to manually delete the figure
```

For anything more complex, you would have to write a separate function which will be called when the figure is closed.